# sqlite: How to get the column id of the selected column?

Tags: c++, sqlite

Given:

- an sqlite database with a table `T`
- the table `T` contains 10 columns - `C0`, `C1` ... `C9`.
- an `sqlite3_stmt` pointer corresponding to `select C3,C2 from T`

OK, so I can fetch the selected column values using the `sqlite3_column_XXX` family of methods (http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob), like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt *s;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, sizeof(query), &s, NULL);
while ((result = sqlite3_step(s)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
  const char *v3 = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(s, 0);
  const char *v2 = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(s, 1);
}
```

What I need is the real index of the selected columns, i.e. 3 for `v3` and 2 for `v2`.

**Motivation:** I want to be able to parse the returned string value into the real column type. Indeed, my schema says that `c3` is a `datetime`, which sqlite treats as `TEXT`. So, `sqlite3_column_type(s, 0)` returns `SQLITE3_TEXT`, but the table metadata (available from `pragma table_info(T)`) retains the string `datetime`, which is the intended type of the column. Knowing it, I can parse the returned string into the respective unix time since the epoch, for instance.

But how can I map the query column index to the table column index:

- query column 0 -> table column 3
- query column 1 -> table column 2

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered embedding that sort of information at a higher level of concern?  The code that *knows* its querying foo from table bar can declare that it wants a date from some column.  Otherwise your relying on introspection from a system that really isn't designed or expected to support it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the sqlite C function [`sqlite3_column_decltype`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_decltype.html) to get the declared column data type from the result stmt?  It doesn't specifically answer your question (getting the original column's index), but could be an alternative way to achieve what you need?